# How to add a div inside a link?

Tags: views, theming, navigation

I have a view accordion which works as it should, but I would like to add a play button to the thumbnails images that are inside the thumbnail!

I´m thinking: just a empty div inside of the a href, where the thumbnail image is placed. But how do I do this?

Any one have a suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: you can do it using rewrite field add you specific tag or image in it by custom html

Comment: Yes that works...almost...my div ends outside of the link. I wrote [field_image] <div class="playbtn"></div>, and it gave me this: <a href=""><img></a>>div class="playbtn"></div>. I trying to get the div inside of the a ref so that I can place on top of the <img>....so it is a link with two images, one that is content related and another that just shows a play button above the other one, without destroying the link!

Comment: See [this general question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1827965/2389310) - pre-HTML5 it wasn't even valid.

Comment: which Drupal you are asking for? 7? 8?